# Is this function pointer with `this` in trailing return type legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, function-pointers

```
class C {
  auto (*foo)() -> decltype(this);
};
```

This code is accepted by GCC, MSVC, and clang, but not icc.

Comment: When your only holdout is icc, even if it isn't legal it may be next time they patch the standard.  ;)

Comment: GCC and clang accept this code even in `-std=c++11` mode, which indicates that their developers do not think this is an extension to standard C++.

Comment: [Clang also allows `struct X { int (*p)() noexcept(sizeof(this)); };`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cvabMXIipNcaX1MI) while [GCC rejects it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BGaZ1w2FpLXC7fWC).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting n4140 (roughly C++14) [expr.prim.general]:

> 3 If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class `X`, the expression `this` is a prvalue of type "pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`" between the optional *cv-qualifer-seq* and the end of the *function-definition*, *member-declarator*, or *declarator*. It shall not appear before the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function (although its type and value category are defined within a static member function as they are within a non-static member function). [...]
>
> 4 Otherwise, if a *member-declarator* declares a non-static data member (9.2) of a class `X`, the expression this is a prvalue of type "pointer to `X`" within the optional *brace-or-equal-initializer*. It shall not appear elsewhere in the *member-declarator*.

Since you're not declaring a member function or member function template, p3 doesn't apply, but this is what would make the code valid for the non-pointer case where you actually declare a member function: the trailing return type is between the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and the end of the declarator, as made clearer in the definition of a `const` member function:

```
auto foo() const -> decltype(this) { }
```

p4 is what applies here though. It allows `this` only to appear in the initialiser. You're putting it elsewhere. p3 doesn't apply, so ICC is correct to reject this.

Comment: Don't you think that the end of first sentence somehow does not match the beginning? I mean at the beginning it is only member function that is listed as a context where `this` have that certain meaning, however at the end it is somehow assumed that such context also includes *member-declarator, or declarator*. Or is there something that starts as member function declaration but ends as declarator? The ending makes me think that p3 actually does apply.

Comment: @VTT No, that's just because a member function or member function template declaration may, depending on the context, be in the form of a *function-definition* (if it includes a definition), a *member-declarator* (if it appears in-class without a definition), or a *declarator* (if it appears outside of a class without a definition).